# Issue with the AutoDesk Forge Viewer API

Tags: javascript, autocad, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

While getting the document to load, I am getting this error

```
wgs.js:21467 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'numGeoms' of undefined
    at d.RenderModel.initialize (wgs.js:21467)
    at a.onModelRootLoadDone (viewer3D.min.js:4484)
    at Worker.p (viewer3D.min.js:4432)
    RenderModel.initialize @ wgs.js:21467
    a.onModelRootLoadDone @ viewer3D.min.js:4484
    p @ viewer3D.min.js:4432
    viewer3D.min.js:4446 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 
    'meshToGeometry' of undefined
        at a.processReceivedMesh (viewer3D.min.js:4446)
        at a.processReceivedMesh2D (viewer3D.min.js:4465)
        at Worker.p (viewer3D.min.js:4432)
        a.processReceivedMesh @ viewer3D.min.js:4446
        a.processReceivedMesh2D @ viewer3D.min.js:4465
        p @ viewer3D.min.js:4432
       validator.html:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x55a2800ad520]GL ERROR:GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete (check) 59 viewer3D.min.js:4446 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meshToGeometry' of undefined
    at a.processReceivedMesh (viewer3D.min.js:4446)
    at a.processReceivedMesh2D (viewer3D.min.js:4465)
    at Worker.p (viewer3D.min.js:4432)
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: You need to show the code which calls this library.

Comment: Which viewer version are you using?? Type `LMV_VIEWER_VERSION` in your browser console will tell.

Comment: LMV_VIEWER_VERSION --> 2.14

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by the use of an outdated version of the viewer.

Currently the Viewer is on Version 3.3 I will suggest doing the migration to solve your problem and also take advantage of all the new functionality.

Here is a list of the changelogs 
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/

And here the blog post about the newer version
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v33